# Upload multiple images via theme options

Tags: theme-options

Is there a simple script out there that would allow multiple images to be uploaded via my theme options page (Which is based on this script - http://buildinternet.com/2010/01/create-custom-option-panels-with-wordpress-2-9/ )?

I need to be able to upload 6 images which will feature in a site-wide slideshow.

Comment: Not really, in 3.3 the media uploader will actually get a decent API you can hook into it seems, so you might want to revisit once that one comes out...

Comment: This is a shameless plug for a theme options framework I helped build which handles image uploads. You would need to create six different image type options, but it would work. http://upthemes.com/upthemes-framework/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/  and also repeater fields addon and gallery addon. If you combined all, then you can make this slider functions and other usefull options inputs for your options pages.